# How to get webcam working with Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

OS: Windows 10 pro

Device: Laptop

I have tried connecting to virtual machine using remote desktop with video caputure checked in Resources tab.

Just to test I tried running Windows Sandbox with `<VideoInput>Enable</VideoInput>` but it also doesn't detect the laptop webcam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hyper-V Requirements for using local resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect#requirements-for-using-local-resources)
gives this list, for adding USB devices:

> - The Hyper-V host must have **Enhanced session mode policy** and
>   **Enhanced session mode** settings turned on.
> - The computer on which you use VMConnect must run Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2016, or Windows Server 2012 R2.
> - The virtual machine must have Remote Desktop Services enabled, and run Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2016, or Windows Server
>   2012 R2 as the guest operating system.

The post
[How to add Webcam to a Hyper-V Virtual Machine](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a11eee73-86e0-4782-b2ab-60dfd19556ab/how-to-add-webcam-to-a-hyperv-virtual-machine?forum=win10itprovirt)
notes that the device should be added via the Local Resources dialog,
which doesn't always come up.

To force the Local Resources dialog to appear, if it doesn't,
you might need to find and delete the config file, which might be located at:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Client\1.0\vmconnect.rdp.{virtual machine GUID}.config`